# Factorising and drawing Markov chains Problem

Tags: probability, markov-chains

My question for today is:

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be a Markov chain, with the subscript denoting the time index. Give a factorisation
of the joint distribution $p(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ that is simplified by the Markov property and draw a graphical
model representing this factorisation.

Ive graphically drawn plenty of Markov chains before but im not too sure about this question ive been given so if anyone can help me out that would be fantastic

Answer (score 0):

Markov chain means given the present, the future is independent from the past.

Given $X_2$, $X_1$ and $X_3$ are independent.

\begin{align}
p(X_1,X_2,X_3) &= p(X_1)p(X_2|X_1)p(X_3|X_1,X_2) \\
&= p(X_1)p(X_2|X_1)p(X_3|X_2)
\end{align}

Notice that $$p(X_3|X_1,X_2) = p(X_3|X_2)$$

due to Markov property.

Comment: Oh I see that makes sense.  How you written $p(X_3|X_1,X_2)$=$p(X_3|X_2)$ to show how its been simplified above??

Comment: yup, I hope it is correct.

Comment: It looks correct, thanks for the help